# R - Problem with leap year in time series data

Tags: r, database, twitter, time-series, leap-year

I noticed that on the raw data set for tweets with specifics hashtags that i collected, whenever the date of the tweet occurred on December 31st, R considered it as the 53rd week of the year, however,  should only have 52 weeks.

When I join another database (Google), which is correct, with the database extracted from twitter, R put these unmatched rows at the end of the dataset - which "broke" the timeseries chronological order. (you can see here) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxsTd.png)
`

This mistake was carried out throughout the data analysis to a point that when I created a new column to add a date variable for my time series graph, these last rows that were out of order were assigned the wrong month - they were wrongly considered as month 1, instead of month 12.

Given such a mistake, in a further chunk, when I joined my main database (twitter) with the database of the firm's social media activity, the last two rows received a zero on the month column, which led to the error in the seasons dummy.

I need to adjust the chronological order to get rid of these miscreated fake leap years

Comment: Not all 53 week years are leap years. [ISO week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) numbered years will have 53 weeks if January 1st was on a Thursday. If you're looking for a common key to join your tables on, using the original dates will probably work better.